# web scraping showing access denied

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, data-science

I am trying to scrap the data from https://www.ambitionbox.com/list-of-companies?page=1 and It is showing access denied error.

I tried using the following:

```py
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win 64 ; x64) Apple WeKit /537.36(KHTML , like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36'}
requests.get('https://www.ambitionbox.com/list-of-companies?page=1', headers=headers).text
```

But it shows `access denied` instead of getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the full curl from your browser and see if it works, you may just need to add a cookie or some other information to it like params (play around with it).

How to get the cURL:
-go into the website and press ctrl+shift+i to open developer tools (or right click and press inspect)

- go into the network tab
- Press on fetch/xhr to only show that
- refresh page
- click on the first requests that are made, press on the response to see what's in them until you see a response with the data you want. In this case it was the first one.
- right click and press copy > copy as curl (bash)
- go to https://curlconverter.com/ and convert it to python.

I got this code from converting the curl to python and it works:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    '_t_ds': '3c23c9511692976818-583c23c951-03c23c951',
    'ak_bmsc': 'DC6C8CDD09BD793241560572B7969658~000000000000000000000000000000~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',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.605537449.1692976822',
    '_gat': '1',
    '_ga_HV7DJVVBCW': 'GS1.1.1692976822.1.0.1692976822.0.0.0',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.542648404.1692976822',
    '_gat_UA-56667153-10': '1',
    'bm_sv': 'C13D97D93968DFD85383D851670D78CC~YAAQN9XdWPCn3/6JAQAAkIBILRQhzfPgNcRf2vB+1s4CvpIw8hm6fneeMmd1APtbV/eEDWcE+pMoGVTfJsoIvDCgcqFl586d/DSZufr2zjXX4AzUFG4qNl9yPD8fru4G0XRmHmlzzrquibOxMYv0EIv9i48mwekXigN7U4KrB7bSgIElr6cCF18kHHUxxBY1eVOTDXyp+sEGLoFPN9XMiWGY7/DLa1ZHGBExZZNhTbecWi0HSRk1qpCYWO5mtpcEO8A4B6A=~1',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.ambitionbox.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    # 'cookie': '_t_ds=3c23c9511692976818-583c23c951-03c23c951; ak_bmsc=DC6C8CDD09BD793241560572B7969658~000000000000000000000000000000~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; _gid=GA1.2.605537449.1692976822; _gat=1; _ga_HV7DJVVBCW=GS1.1.1692976822.1.0.1692976822.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.542648404.1692976822; _gat_UA-56667153-10=1; bm_sv=C13D97D93968DFD85383D851670D78CC~YAAQN9XdWPCn3/6JAQAAkIBILRQhzfPgNcRf2vB+1s4CvpIw8hm6fneeMmd1APtbV/eEDWcE+pMoGVTfJsoIvDCgcqFl586d/DSZufr2zjXX4AzUFG4qNl9yPD8fru4G0XRmHmlzzrquibOxMYv0EIv9i48mwekXigN7U4KrB7bSgIElr6cCF18kHHUxxBY1eVOTDXyp+sEGLoFPN9XMiWGY7/DLa1ZHGBExZZNhTbecWi0HSRk1qpCYWO5mtpcEO8A4B6A=~1',
    'if-none-match': '"4ec84-bQPoHteoPnvu6Oq3Zb0fGjwnYn8"',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Microsoft Edge";v="116"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.54',
}

params = {
    'page': '1',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.ambitionbox.com/list-of-companies', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```